# Rails hide #anchor tag in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, anchor

I am using JavaScript to navigate to anchors on the main page. From within the main page, when I click an anchor link, the url remains the same: localhost/ (using javascript ScrollTo), but when I try to link to that anchor tag from a separate page it displays the anchor tag in the url. localhost/#anchor.

How can I mask the url to not display the anchor tag?

```
<li><%= link_to "Anchor", root_path(:anchor => 'anchor') %></li>
```

jquery:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which library provide this scrollTo method, prototype? jquery? The answer can be quite different.

Comment: Yes I am using jquery. Code pasted below.

Answer (score 4):

When you click on the anchor on the main page you're not actually submitting a request to Rails, you're just executing a click handler.  But when you are coming from another page then you ***are*** submitting a request to Rails and the #fragment is the only way for anyone to know where on the page to scroll to.

Best you can do is detect the #fragment in JS when you load the page, scroll to the right place, and remove the fragment with

```
history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#')))
```

assuming you have a browser that supports `replaceState`.  You can use [History.js](http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/) if you want to be nice to older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `window.location.hash.replace('#', '');`